# Как лучше всего реализовать расчет на Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Надо сделать мини расчет. Допустим, есть сайт-магазин, кладем товары в корзину, товары имеют верстку:

```
<tr class="cart-order">
    <td align="left">тестовый товар 2</td>
    <td><b><span class="weight">30</span> кг.</b></td>
    <td><span class="price">5500</span> руб.</td>
    <td align="center">
        <input class="count" type="text" size="2" title="изменить количество" value="2">
    </td>
</tr>
```

В форме видно, что имеется вес и цена. Вес, при указании более 1 товара не умножается.
Мне необходимо сделать расчет, допустим есть два товара в корзине и одного из них указано количество - 2. Надо умножить количество товара на вес, чтобы в отдельной колонке вывести общий вес для каждого товара. Основной алгоритм взял такой: собрать все объекты на странице с классом .cart-order, а потом в цикле for взять из каждого объекта значения веса и количества и умножить.
Дело в том, что если сделать так:

```
var orders = $('tr.cart-order');
console.log(orders);
```

то я получу что то типа `m.fn.init(2)` я так понял это объекты.
а если так:

```
console.log(orders[0]);
```

то получу DOM, товара, все верно, но как потом вытащить оттуда значения цены, веса и количества, чтобы потом с ними производить операции? Или я вообще неправильный алгоритм выбрал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз вы используете jQuery, то можете применить .find()  Примерно так

```js
orders.each(function(){
  var weight = $(this).find(".weight").text(); //Вес 
  var price = $(this).find(".price").text(); //Цена
});
```

Comment: `var weight = +$(this).find(".weight").text();`

Comment: @Igor, да, точно, забыл че-то

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает! А то я резко с php переключился на js и jquery и взгляд замыленый уже!